# swift generics return first and last element

Tags: swift, generics, generic-programming, anyobject

I'm trying to get used to generics (never used them in  objc) and want to write a toy function that takes an object of any type () and returns the first and last element. Hypothetically, I'd only use this on an array or a string - I keep getting an error that  has no subscript members. I totally understand that the error message is telling me swift has no clue that T may potentially hold a type that does have subscripts - I just want to know how to get around this.

```
func firstAndLastFromCollection<T>(a:T?) {
    var count: Int = 0

    for item in a as! [AnyObject] {
        count++
    }
    if count>1 {
        var first = a?[0]
        var last = a?[count-1]
        return (first, last)
      }
    return something else here
 }
```

Do I need to typecast somewhere here (which would kind of defeat the purpose here, as I'd need to downcast as either a string or an array, adding code and lessening how generic this func is)?

Comment: "takes an object of any type" – don't you mean takes an array of objects of a generic type? In that case, you'll want to make your argument take a generic array, i.e `[T]`

Comment: I'd like to have the ability to pass a string and pull out the first and last character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are talking about collections, let's use the `CollectionType`:

```
func firstAndLastFromCollection<T: CollectionType>(a: T) -> (T.Generator.Element, T.Generator.Element)? {
    guard !a.isEmpty else {
        return nil
    }

    return (a.first!, a.lazy.reverse().first!)
}

print(firstAndLastFromCollection(["a", "b", "c"])) // ("a", "c")
print(firstAndLastFromCollection("abc".characters)) // ("a", "c")
print(firstAndLastFromCollection(0..<200)) // (0, 199)
print(firstAndLastFromCollection([] as [String]))   // nil
```

If you specify your generic type to also conform to bidirectional index:

```
func firstAndLastFromCollection<T: CollectionType where T.Index : BidirectionalIndexType>(...) -> ...
```

then you can call `last` directly:

```
return (a.first!, a.last!)
```

If we decide to implement it using a category, we don't need generics at all:

```
extension CollectionType {
    func firstAndLast() -> (Generator.Element, Generator.Element)? {
        guard !self.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }

        return (self.first!, self.lazy.reverse().first!)
    }
}

extension CollectionType where Index: BidirectionalIndexType {
    func firstAndLast() -> (Generator.Element, Generator.Element)? {
        guard !self.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }

        return (self.first!, self.last!)
    }
}

print("abc".characters.firstAndLast())
```

Swift is a *protocol* oriented language. Usually you will find yourself extend protocols more than extending classes or structs.

Comment: Much appreciated. Just learned a ton from this - went to reading about generators, guards and lazy mapping functions. Genuinely, thanks for leading me down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return the first and the last element then it's probably safe assuming the input param is an array of some kind of type.

So you can implement your function this way

```
func firstAndLast<T>(list:[T]) -> (first:T, last:T)? {
    guard let first = list.first, last = list.last else { return nil }
    return (first, last)
}
```

The function does return a tuple of 2 element, both have the same type of the generic element of the input array.
The returned tuple is an option because if the array is empty then nil is returned.

### Examples

```
let nums = firstAndLast([1,2,3,4])
let words = firstAndLast(["One", "Two", "Three"])
```

As you can verify the type of the generic element into the array becomes the type of the elements inside the tuple.

In the example above `nums` is inferred to be `(Int, Int)?` and `words` `(Words, Words)?`

More examples

```
let emptyList: [String] = []
firstAndLast(emptyList) // nil
```

### Extension

Finally you can also write this code as an extension of Array.

```
extension Array {
    var firstAndLast: (first:Element, last:Element)? {
        guard let first = self.first, last = self.last else { return nil }
        return (first, last)
    }
}
```

Now you can write

```
let aCoupleOfShows = ["Breaking Bad", "Better Call Saul", "Mr Robot"].firstAndLast
```

Again, if you check the type of the constant `aCoupleOfShows` you'll see that is a `(first: String, last: String)?`. Swift automatically did infer the correct type.

### Last example

In the comments you said you wanted the first and last chars of a String. here it is the code if you use the extension above

```
if let chars = Array("Hello world".characters).firstAndLast {
    print("First char is \(chars.first), last char is \(chars.last) ")
}

//>> First char is H, last char is d
```